# How do I add a count down timer on a specific post after comment box

Tags: timer, countdown

How do I add a count down timer on a specific post after comment box

After the countdown finish a post link will appear

Any help will be appreciated

I tried many plug-in but the plug-in not working properly or the short code not working properly I don't know why